# Jasperreports-6.3.0 Webapp sample compile throws exception

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, jasper-reports, classnotfoundexception

I'm trying to test the webapp sample of the [JasperReport Library](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jasperreports/files/jasperreports/JasperReports%206.3.0/).
I load the war into eclipse, Tomcat v8.0 Server. Also, I can run it, and view index page. But to test this app, the first step is to compile the JRXML.

But, I can't because throws some exceptions:

- JSP Example:

`scriptlets.WebappScriptlet cannot be resolved to a type`

- Servlet Example:

`javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class servlets.CompileServlet
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: servlets.CompileServlet`

You can see these classes into `src` folder:

[image: Project structure]

Comment: Same error without solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7913457/cannot-compile-webapp-sample-of-jasperreports?rq=1

Comment: Without further info  it's impossible to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a bug in 6.3.0 version.

Resolved in 6.3.1 version. You can download from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jasperreports/files/jasperreports/JasperReports%206.3.1/jasperreports-6.3.1-project.zip/download).